# Sprite Animation Toolkits for iPhone

Tags: ios

Does anyone know of any good (and preferably **free**) Sprite Animation Toolkits/Libraries for iOS development?

This library should be able to handle the collision detection and the movement of the sprites.  Back in the 90's there was a Pascal library called Sprite Animation Toolkit by Ingemar Ragnemalm that handled a lot of the heft to create animations and the such.  I am just wondering if there is anything like that in the iOS world?

Comment: Do you have any requirements for this piece of software? Or do you just want to make texture atlases?

Comment: I recommend spriter http://www.brashmonkey.com/.

Answer (score 2):

- Cocos2d-iphone is a great open source framework for iOS
- Cocos2d-x will give you automatic porting for Android so you might want to
  check it as well
- Both are based on Open GL which is another open source graphic library
- Box2d is also a great open source resource for 2d graphics

Comment: Not sure what this list has to do with animation frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not specifically a sprite animation library, is [Cocos 2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) any use to you? You can also look at the source which might help you create a sprite animation library of your own.